# Factoring $x^8-x^4+1$ over $GF(7)$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, factoring

Could anyone suggest any good way to do it? (The only way I can think of is by looking for roots (There are none), checking a factorization into the product of a 6 and a 2 polynomial (Many unknowns for the coefficients), checking a factorization of a 5 and 3, and finally one of two 4 degrees. (And each check probably takes lot's of time, since it contains many variables)

Is there any smarter way to do it?

Comment: An easy check for a certain type of two polynomials of degree four is looking for $a,b\in\mathbb F_7$ (or GF(7) if you prefer) such that $ab\equiv 1$ and $a+b\equiv 1$. Then we would have $x^8-x^4+1=(x^4-a)(x^4-b)$. That's at least a good place to start.

Comment: You might recognize this as the 24th cyclotomic polynomial. So all its roots are primitive 24th roots of unity. The multiplicative group of $GF(49)$ is cyclic of order $49-1=48$, so contains all those roots. The multiplicative group of $GF(7)$ does not contain any (as you observed). Therefore we know that the polynomial will factor into a product of the minimal polynomials of those primitive roots of unity - all of them quadratic. See Martin Brandenburg's excellent answer for finding them (tacitly utilizing this).

Comment: @Jyrki: Why not posting this as an answer? I had also tried to look for cyclotomic polynomials or suitable substitutions first. But I didn't get up to $24$. :)

Comment: @Martin: I appreciate the sentiment, but I think I'll pass. Your answer already contains the bit that I can extract from cyclotomy - namely that the primitive sixth roots in $GF(7)$, i.e. $3$ and $5$ give rise to the factors $x^4-3$ and $x^4-5$. I don't see any really neat tricks that would give the factorization down to quadratics any easier than your approach - well, may be the one in my comment to your answer:-).

Answer (score 7):

First one substitutes $z=x^4$ and arrives at $z^2-z+1=0$. Quadratic polynomials are easy to factor (over any field of characteristic $\neq 2$), here we get $(z-3)(z-5)$. Using a bit of Galois theory (see below) one can find $x^4-3=(x^2+2x+2)(x^2+5x+2)$ and $x^4-5=(x^2+x+4)(x^2+6x+4)$ and these polynomials of degree $2$ are irreducible.

---

The Galois group of the polynomial is generated by the Frobenius $\alpha \mapsto \alpha^7$, and it acts on the roots. This action is transitive iff the polynomial is irreducible. More precisely, every orbit gives rise to an irreducible factor. Let $\alpha \in \overline{\mathbb{F}_7}$ be a root of $x^4-3$. One checks directly that $\alpha \notin \mathbb{F}_7$, hence $\alpha \neq \alpha^7$. But $\alpha^{7^2}=\alpha \cdot (\alpha^4)^{12}=\alpha \cdot 3^{12}=\alpha$. Therefore, $(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^7) \in \mathbb{F}_7[x]$ is an irreducible factor of $x^4-3$. The constant term is $\alpha^8=(\alpha^4)^2=3^2=2$. The linear coefficient is $\alpha+\alpha^7$, whose square is $\alpha^2+2 \alpha^8 + \alpha^{14}=\alpha^2 + 2 (\alpha^4)^2+\alpha^2 (\alpha^4)^3=\alpha^2+2 \cdot 2 + \alpha^2 \cdot 6=4$, hence $\alpha+\alpha^7  = \pm 2$. Thus, we find  $x^4-3=(x^2+2x+2)(x^2+5x+2)$.

Of course this can also be verified by a direct computation, but using Galois theory (which is quite easy for finite fields) we can *derive* the irreducible factors. No brute force search or algorithm is necessary.

Comment: +1 Nice answer, and I suspect very helpful to! ;-) $\quad$ Seriously, you're answer is spot on!

Comment: +1 Very nice, indeed! You can also use the known factorization of $x^4+4$ as
$$x^4-3=x^4+4=(x^4+4x^2+4)-4x^2=(x^2+2)^2-(2x)^2.$$ May be something similar is there for $x^4-5$ as well, but your approach is already very good.

Comment: @Jyrki: This is a very nice alternative. Let us know when you find something like that for $x^4-5$.

Answer (score 3):

I will follow up on my comment here, because I have found a strategy.

> An easy check for a certain type of two polynomials of degree four is looking for $a,b∈_7$ (or GF(7) if you prefer) such that $ab≡1$ and $a+b≡1$. Then we would have $x^8−x^4+1=(x^4−a)(x^4−b)$. That's at least a good place to start.

EDIT: I screwed up in here somewhere and so have removed what I had written. Sorry to have now double-posted.

Comment: Perhaps its just my ignorance in number theory, but how does this compare with [Wolfram|Alpha's answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x^8+-+x^4+%2B+1+over+GF%287%29)?

Comment: Well that means I screwed up and I will edit my post to account for that.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Berlekamp's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm).

Comment: It would be a wonderful answer when you explain this algorithm via this example here.